# How to send email with AWS SES using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, actionmailer

I am trying to use html templates to send invitation emails. Currently I'm using [aws-ses](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses) gem like this:

```
  ses = AWS::SES::Base.new(
      :access_key_id     => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
  ses.send_email(:to => ..., :source => ..., :subject => ..., :html_body => <p> Hi how are you</p>)
```

and I send the html code as a string in `:html_body`. This works fine.

What I want to do is use a template, and store it in a separate file, for example `invite_email.html.erb`, which will be stored under `app/views/user_mailer/`.

So I figured I had to use action mailer to use rendered views. I setup action mailer to use AWS::SES gem, and followed the rails guides to setup action mailer with `rails g mailer UserMailer`. I have a UserMailer, a layout, and I restarted the server. My `developement.rb` looks like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

and I initialized `:ses` like this in `initializers/action_mailer.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
                                   access_key_id: 'XXXXX',
                                   secret_access_key: 'XXXXX'
```

The server responds: `UserMailer#invite_email: processed outbound mail in 184.0ms`

The problem is, I still don't get any emails. I tried in the test environment with the same settings in `environments/test.rb` on a different machine, and still no emails. The server shows the layout is being rendered and the email is being processed. Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using the following approach to make `ActionMailer` to send emails using AWS SES. I have created a simple wrapper around [fog-aws](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) gem and added delivery method similar to what you use in your question. I've decided to use `fog-aws` gem because it allows me to use IAM roles instead of specifying access credentials explicitly.

I've created `lib/aws/ses_mailer.rb` file with following content:

```
module AWS
  class SESMailer
    attr_reader :settings

    def initialize(options = {})
      @fog_mailer = Fog::AWS::SES.new(options)
      @settings = {}
    end

    delegate :send_raw_email, to: :@fog_mailer

    alias_method :deliver!, :send_raw_email
    alias_method :deliver, :send_raw_email
  end
end
```

Then add delivery method in `config/initializers/amazon_ses.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SESMailer, use_iam_profile: true
```

Then enable it for particular environment:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

And now you may send emails with AWS SES.

Comment: Hey, where did you specify your IAM roles? Do you have to include the `access_keys` in the `settings` hash?

Comment: @achabacha322, You don't need to explicitly specify role since it is used to launch your EC2 instance.

Comment: I am getting `uninitialized constant AWS`.  Don't I need to `require AWS::SESMailer` somewhere?  Also, do I just need to set IAM defaults for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` in `~/.fog` as described in the gem Readme?

Comment: I figured it out (and didn't need the `fog-aws` gem).  Answer posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245628/aws-ses-timeout?answertab=active#tab-top.

Comment: Solid, helpful answer; just some potential clarifications: in order for the IAM role to be dynamically associated with the ec2 instance, the instance must be launched within a VPC, and not classic ec2 mode. additionally, if you're using any other AMI besides amazon linux, or 3rd party market place ami's that handle it, the aws tools are not installed by default, and that will have to happen in order for the instance to get the iam role.